# How to calculate accuracy in a monte-carlo type simulation

Tags: monte-carlo, accuracy, uncertainty

I've got a monte-carlo simulations that I've programmed. It works well and follows trends with published work from my field (my field is engineering). I would like to calculate accuracy propagation through my simulation due to the input data possibly being off by a fixed amount - what I mean by this is that the input is x+-b (where b is a constant significantly smaller than x).

For simple calculations I can calculate how all the different inputs uncertainties propagate however when I move the the monte-carlo side of the calculations I am just lost. The underlying principal of the test is that any single object can be located in any one of a number of positions, and picking a single position at random many times is equivalent to the distribution of positions if the precise location were to be simulated. So the values I use to calculate the finite number of possible positions have a simple x+-b accuracy, but then how to I represent the accuracy of calculations based on the randomly selected location?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I gather that some statistical parameters in your Monte Carlo simulation depend on the input data.

This is so, because you say that when you offset your input data, the random generation does not follow suit.

The parameters I am talking about are those of the statistical distribution you use to generate the "random positions".

You should derive these parameters from your input data and modify your code accordingly.

If you are using a normal distribution, then these parameters are the mean and standard deviation.